# Save textView color in listView with sharedPreferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have `listView` and a custom adapter in fragment, which contains only a textView called `list_content`. I want the user to change the color of the textView onClick. So far this is my relevant code onCreate along with listView setOnItemClickedListener:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grocery_list, container, false);

    //Load text color
    color = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.android.me", MODE_PRIVATE);
    colourValue = color.getString("colourValue", null);

    //list view
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.groceryListView);


    //arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, groceries);
    arrayAdapter = new customAdapter(getContext(), groceries);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //list view click listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            list_content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);

            color = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.android.me", MODE_PRIVATE);
            colourValue = color.getString("colourValue", null);

            if (list_content.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.parseColor("#000000")){ //Check if item is checked or not | if (list_content.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.parseColor("#000000")) {

                color.edit().putString("colourValue","#a7a7a7").apply();

            } else {

                color.edit().putString("colourValue","#000000").apply();

            }

            list_content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colourValue));

        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

I have two problems. First, when I click on my item, the color wont always change back and forth. And the second, the color won't save when I switch fragments/close and open the app. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you start the app it seems to load the colourValue shared pref, but it doesn't immediately do anything with it.  It seems like when you click, it'll use whatever the last colourValue that was saved in the shared preferences, but not related to the state of the view that you created when your app started.  Maybe you need to load this colourValue and apply it to the list view when you start?  If you want to save the state for each of the list view items, you're going to need to do a little more work and save the entire list's state.  Not sure if shared prefs is going to be easy for this.  Maybe create a state object and serialize it into GSON and store that into a shared pref using Gson or something.

I think there's a little too much going on here and you might want to try to get this working first before you try persisting the color state of the list.  Make sure the toggling on and off works.

Another issue here, I think, is you're managing one value for this color state, but you could have multiple items in your list.  If I click the first item a bunch of times, it might toggle, but if I click the second item, it's going to toggle based on whatever state the first item was in (because it uses the value that was saved in the shared preferences each time).

Also, I don't see you calling SharedPreferences commit(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()

Comment: Your answer cleared it up quite a bit. I guess sharedPreferences won't really do this, I'll try other methods. Thanks.